# How to deserialize a KeyValuePair json array into a C# Class?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON string that looks like this:

```json
{
   "Attributes":[
      {
         "Key":"prop1",
         "Value":"prop1value"
      },
      {
         "Key":"prop2",
         "Value":{
            "Id":"30da85a5-682e-eb11-a813-000d3a4dade3",
            "LogicalName":"AnotherClass"
         }
      },
      ...,
      {
         "Key":"propN",
         "Value":"propNvalue"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to deserialize these keyvalue pairs into a class object like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public AnotherClass prop2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string propN { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I'm looping through each kv pair and dynamically adding them to a new `JObject` then, deserializing that like this:

```
var _newJObject = new JObject();
foreach (var att in Attributes)
{
    _newJObject.Add(att.Key, att.Value);
}
var _myclass = _newJObject.ToObject<MyClass>();
```

But is there a more direct way to accomplish this without manually creating the `_newJObject` intermediary?

Comment: Do you control the format of the original JSON? Because if so, you could directly use an object instead of an array of objects, and then you could deserialize it like any object.

Comment: the question is, "Does the property value only have two representations, and is there a schema, why is it sometimes a string and sometimes an object?"

Comment: I have no control over how the JSON is formatted. The "Value" can be any primitive or complex object.